# SSRS Web Service URL can not access in another network

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, ssrs-2012

I have my SSRS configured on a server different from my network, I configured ssrs web service URL in native mode ,I would like to add this web service URL in my asp.net mvc4 , but the problem is whenever i add this URL in service reference it says link not found.
I have the ports in the manner mentioned below in the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934283.aspx
and also tried doing this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f7a8ba16-173f-4537-aa2c-5b85a2d83d0e/unable-to-access-ssrs-2008-report-manager-url-from-other-machines-which-are-in-same-network?forum=sqlreportingservices

Please Help..!

Comment: Are you able to address the webservice by entering the address into a browser?

Comment: I am able to access the URL on the machine where SSRS is configured. I have turned off the firewall too, but i can not access the URL from my machine which is in different domain.

Comment: You need to troubleshoot / determine the connectivity issue you are having.  If you can't hit the WebService URL in a browser you are not going to be able to grab the WSDL in VisualStudio.  Can you `ping` the DNS name of the server in question (from your machine)?

Comment: No iam not able to ping the server from my machine ..!I have the reporting server configured in Microsoft cloud and iam able to access it through another Microsoft cloud server , i guess there is some firewall blockage with the URL being exposed to public. what say ..?

Comment: That helps me understand the situation better.  Do you have any SSRS instance that is addressable on your network?  What you need to do is generate the proxy class for the WebService, which only needs to occur once (at design-time) and should be possible using a local SSRS instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yayyy..!I figured it, I have to include a new end point in cloud server so that it can accept request from outside net